# replace text inside some text with other

Tags: php, javascript, html, shortcode

I created some shortcodes for some images but when page loads I want to replace it with a img html line.

Is there any way to do it?

Or maybe get all the text in that textarea and replace the [something]asd[/something] with the code I want to show in the end.

All im doing is using a library that when we click and image it puts the next text on the textarea.

[item=myitem]

Then I want to replace this with:

```
<img class="itemtooltip" alt="" src="myitem.png" width="64" height="64" data-tip="myitem" />
```

the replacement process is on another page. I have all the text area on a string so I want to search in that text and replace

Comment: If you post your code, you can be answered in seconds...

Comment: it sounds like **str_replace** function is necessary in here!

Comment: or..it can be a simple .html() method that is needed to replace the text with an image.

Comment: done. edited with what I need

Comment: Set your textarea section to display:none .on() click or on submit(), then display your new <img> in its place.  Real easy job via jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = '[item=myitem]';
$new = '<img class="itemtooltip" alt="" src="';
$new2 = '.png" width="64" height="64" data-tip="myitem" />';

$var = str_replace('[item=',"", $var);
$var = rtrim(trim($var), ']');
echo $new.$var.$new2;
```

Comment: @Susheel Mishra, I have a feeling the OP is leaving out that the replacement process is occurring on a click event...

Comment: no, the replacement process is on another page. I have all the text area on a string so I want to search in that text and replace

Comment: all textarea in one strinf or different in different string?

Comment: give me example string and desired string

Comment: This [item=myitem] is the best thing ever but this [item=myitem2] is better.

After process should be:
This <img class="itemtooltip" alt="" src="myitem.png" width="64" height="64" data-tip="myitem" /> is the best but this <img class="itemtooltip" alt="" src="myitem2.png" width="64" height="64" data-tip="myitem2" /> is better

Comment: There are more than 2 items and only the text after '=' changes.

Comment: if still this does not work then , use preg_replace with RE ,search for [item=myitem], and use above replace,

Comment: yours doesnt work with a large text. it always makes an image. and preg_replace doesnt let me remove the myItem :\

Comment: preg_replace worked. : ) | Well kinda... Need to figure out if I can get the name it finds out